# I'm trying to give my formatted answer a name and it's not working

Tags: python, format

```
 for x in range(1.11):
    print ('Number: {0:2d} Square: {1:3d} Cube: {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    for x in range(1.11):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `.` instead of a `,` in `for x in range(1.11):` It should read:

```
for x in range(1,11):
    print ('Number: {0:2d} Square: {1:3d} Cube: {2:4d}'.format(x, x*x, x*x*x))
```